# stop finder replacing colons with slashes in filenames

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

When I rename a file in Finder, any colons are "rendered" as forward slashes.

If I have a file named "0:30", selecting it in finder, pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the filename copies "0/30" to the clipboard instead of "0:30"

How can I make the finder file rename interface treat colons as colons?

Comment: The issue is that for HFS+ the directory separator stored on disk is actually : and not / so there are mapping issues. On APFS I created a file in terminal 0:30 and Finder (and other File Managers) shows it as 0/30 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298479/151019

Comment: Like others, I would urge you not to use colon or slash in filenames. Consider them reserved for the file system's use. Other OSes\file systems tend to have much larger list of reserved/forbidden characters.

Answer (score 8):

It is historic. In Classic Mac OS, `:` was the path separator, not `/`. (Classic Mac OS itself copied the `:` as the path separator from [SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_SOS) for the Apple III.)

OS X is based on Unix (technically [XNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU), with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliance), and so the Unix parts, such as the command-line tools, used `/` as the directory separator. However, the GUI and the actual file-system used on disks ([HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)) had to deal with the Classic Mac OS apps, which were using `:` as the directory separator, just as they always had.

Thus, for backwards-compatibility, the GUI layer (i.e., the Finder) does not allow `:` characters to be used in file names and Unix does not allow `/`. The Finder is responsible for mapping one to the other.

For more information, see [ldav1s's answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298479), which cites [a USENIX 2000 paper, "The Challenges of Integrating the Unix and MAC OS Environments"](http://www.wsanchez.net/papers/USENIX_2000/) that describes some of this history.

Comment: So it is not possible to avoid this mapping?

Comment: And I would add: NEVER use ":" or "/" in any file names. It is too confusing to have a file show a different name in the Finder and in Terminal. And don't use these on other OSes either, because you may need to access that file on a Mac someday, and the same confusion will pop up.

Comment: Side note: [on Windows neither the colon nor the forward slash are allowed in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: Why does 2021 Finder maintain backwards-compatibility with this obsolete 1980s Operating System? The file system doesn't, Finder only "renders" a colon as a slash.

Comment: @mivk I noticed this weirdness because I was putting timestamps into filenames. Hard to choose any other sensible delimiter for that, do you have recommendations?

Comment: @theonlygusti The file system already has time stamps in metadata that you could use.

Comment: @theonlygusti: in such cases, I use letters. For example with the `date` command and it's formatting, I would use `date +%F_%Hh%M` to get "2021-08-05_17h53" or `date +%F_%Hh%Mm%Ss`to get "2021-08-05_17h54m12s" etc. which are all fine in filenames on any platform.

Comment: @theonlygusti or just use an ISO format 1753 - you don't need separators and in fact I am more used to seeing 24hr times without the separator

Comment: @mvirk as well as ":" or "/" I would avoid "\"

Comment: @mivk Thanks for the good suggestion, I actually like how that looks too. mmmmmm, in my case it's timestamps in videos, like saying to a friend "skip to 7:04". Using ISO format for this would be very unusual.

Comment: @theonlygusti The use of : on disk is not obsolete in 2023 HFS+ disks still use : as separator and changing the disk format would be a massive issue for all disks written before that release.